# Filter Json Array to custom Data JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, json, filter, logic

This is my first time working with json and I'm having a hard time trying to filter an array I'm trying to get all values Document ID /Page

```java
datalist = {"DocA|1", "DocA|2, "DocA|3, "DocA|4,, "DocB|1, "DocB|3" , "DocC|1"}
JSONArray jsonObject = json.getJSONArray("datalist");
```

How to create filter value list ?
DocA page 1,2,3,4
DocB page 1
DocC page

Comment: What is `json` in your example?  You should clarify your question.  It seems your input is a list of formatted strings which should be converted into a map: `Map<String, List<Integer>>`.  Which JSONArray you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to convert the input array of String into specified map of document IDs to the list of page IDs, this can be implemented as follows using Java 8 Stream API:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] input = {"DocA|1", "DocA|2", "DocA|3", "DocA|4", "DocB|1", "DocB|3", "DocC|1"};
        
        Map<String, List<Integer>> data = Arrays.stream(input) // get stream of Strings
              .map(s -> s.split("\\|")) // split each string into array using | delimiter
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                  arr -> arr[0], // use documentId as key
                  Collectors.mapping(arr -> Integer.parseInt(arr[1]), Collectors.toList())) // parse page IDs and collect them to list
        );

        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{DocA=[1, 2, 3, 4], DocB=[1, 3], DocC=[1]}
```

Comment: What is `json` in your example?  I asked for that clarification an hour ago in the comment.